# Finding operation using for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript

I've wrote a function to check relations between 3 numbers

For example "1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 6, 2, 3" would be "addition, multiplication, addition, division"

The third number is the result of an operation performed using the previous two numbers.

I want to print operations in this order of preference( addition -> subtraction -> multiplication -> division)

Here's my code. It seems like it doesn't work in the way I intended.

It would be appreciated if someone could help me on this.

```js
function sayMeOperations(str) {
  let arr = str.split(" ").map(Number);
  let newArr = [];

  let add = 'addition';
  let sub = 'subtraction';
  let multi = 'multiplication';
  let div = 'division';

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 2] === arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) {
      newArr.push(add);
    } else if (arr[i + 2] === arr[i] - arr[i + 1]) {
      newArr.push(sub);
    } else if (arr[i + 2] === arr[i] * arr[i + 1]) {
      newArr.push(multi);
    } else if (arr[i + 2] === arr[i] / arr[i + 1]) {
      newArr.push(div);
    } else {}
  }
  return newArr.join(", ");
}

console.log(sayMeOperations("1 2 3 6 0 6 2 3"));
console.log(sayMeOperations("9 3 12 0 12"));
```

Comment: "It seems like it doesn't work in the way I intended." - could you share the input it fails with, what the expected result would be, and what the actual result is? At a glance your code looks OK, but I may have missed something or be misunderstanding what you intend.

Comment: I don't get how you did get "addition, multiplication, addition, division" out of those numbers.

Comment: 3 and 6 do not seem to be included

Comment: @BülentAkgül 1+2=3 is addition, 2*3=6 is multiplication, 6+0=6 is addition, 6/2=3 is division.

Comment: @Gerard They're apparently skipping the ones that don't correspond to any operation.

Comment: So 3,6 is skipped because there's no operation that produces `0`.

Comment: According to the snippet, it's producing the correct result for the sample input you gave. What's the problem?

Comment: What happened 3,6 and 0,6? Why was the passed?

Comment: @BülentAkgül See my comments above.

Comment: What would `2, 2, 2` produce: addition or multiplication (or power)?

Comment: @iAmOren Neither? Did you mean `2,2,4`? The question says there's an order of preference: addition, subtraction, multiplication.

Comment: I did mean `2, 2, 4`...
Where is Jessie?
Is he a second account for you, @Barmar?

Comment: Is your input separated by commas or spaces? `str.split(" ").map(Number)` only works if they're separated by spaces.

Comment: @iAmOren No, I'm not Jessie. I'm just repeating what the question already says, and what seems to be obvious from the example.

Comment: "doesn't work in the way I intended" isn't a clear explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the late reply and my explanation wasn't clear. If I try console.log(sayMeOperations("9 3 12 0 12"), I get  'addition, division, addition' but it should be 'addition, addition'. If third number is not related to previous two numbers it should null..

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for your comment. My explanation wasn't clear. When I try console.log(sayMeOperations("9 3 12 0 12"), I get 'addition, division, addition' but it should be 'addition, addition'. If third number is not related to previous two numbers then I don't want them show nothing.

Comment: @Jessie I just tried that in the code snippet above, it returned `addition, addition`

Comment: I don't see where you're getting division from in those numbers, and it doesn't happen above.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your comment. I'm trying this on the website called codewars. I've must missed something...

Comment: Make sure you get the delimiters in the input right.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the "return early" style, so I broke part of this into another
function:

```js
function map(n, n2, n3) {
   if (n3 == n + n2) {
      return 'addition';
   }
   if (n3 == n - n2) {
      return 'subtraction';
   }
   if (n3 == n * n2) {
      return 'multiplication';
   }
   if (n3 == n / n2) {
      return 'division';
   }
   return false;
}

function sayMeOperations(str) {
   let arr = str.split(', ').map(Number);
   let newArr = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
      let s_op = map(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]);
      if (s_op) {
         newArr.push(s_op);
      }
   }
   return newArr.join(', ');
}

const s = sayMeOperations('1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 6, 2, 3');
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran this after I fixed the endpoint to speed up the final check case. I also replaced the split by space to allow for comma delineated lists:

```
        function sayMeOperations(str) {
          let arr = str.split(",").map(Number);
          let newArr = [];
          
          let add = 'addition';
          let sub = 'subtraction';
          let multi = 'multiplication';
          let div = 'division';
          
         
          for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 3; i++) {
            if(arr[i + 2] === arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) {
              newArr.push(add);
            } else if(arr[i + 2] === arr[i] - arr[i + 1]) {
              newArr.push(sub);
            } else if(arr[i + 2] === arr[i] * arr[i + 1]) {
              newArr.push(multi);
            } else{
              newArr.push(div);
            } 
          }
          return newArr.join(", ");
        }
```

And used your input of "1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 6, 2, 3" and got "addition, multiplication, division, addition, division"

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the problem was and what you changed to get that result.

Comment: Your code is not the code that the op posted.
Your post is not an answer.
Where is the division check?
Why to length - 3?
I vote to delete.

Comment: I was showing that it worked but with minor changes to the for loop. like end distance and fixing the last else statement. I will add this. Thanks!

Comment: The last else statement didn't need fixing.  Perhaps: suggest a "no operation match" or some other message.
Your output doesn't show it worked: 3/6 is not 0 - well, unless you are doing integer arithmetic(!).